# How do I "find" in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#start").find(divs where class=desc).show()

<div id="start">
<div class="desc" style="display:none;">I am visible.</div>
</div>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just like the `jQuery()` function, `find()` takes a CSS selector as an argument.

```
$("#start").find("div.desc").show();
```

`find` is the equivalent of context searching, so the above is the same as:

```
$("div.desc", "#start").show();
```

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Are you sure those the same? The first would find a div with a class of 'desc' that has a parent of #start and then show it. The scond would find both any div with a class of 'desc' and #start and show them all.

Comment: @DA: Selector context uses the `.find()` method anyway, so yes, they are the same.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context

Comment: @DA: the #start string is a second parameter, not part of the selector.

Comment: Is there a difference between $("div.desc, #start") and $("div.desc", "#start")? Maybe that's where I'm confused.

Comment: @DA: Yes, comma separations inside a selector will combine the results of both selectors.  Supplying a selector as a second parameter to the jQuery function tells jQuery to only search descendants of that elements matching that selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#start").find("div.desc").show()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$("#start.desc").show();
```

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/9cg8D/ for the working example.